# If a sequence of $C^2$ function converges in $L^2$, then what happens to the differential images of them?

Tags: functional-analysis, closed-graph

(1) Let $u_n$, $u \in C^2([0,1])$ and $u_n \to u$ in $L^2([0,1])$. If $u_n'' \to v$ in $L^2([0,1])$, then could we say $v = u''$?

(2) Also, could we choose $u_n \in C^2([0,1])$ such that $u_n \to u$ in $L^2([0,1])$ and $u_n'' \to v$, where $v$ is not continuous.

These questions are from John K. Hunter's Applied Analysis. Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: yes to both. What kind of help do you need??

Comment: @daw Thank you for your comment. Yes, I need some help for both of my questions. :)

Answer (score 1):

For (2) take $u_n(x)=\frac {x^{n}} {n(n+1)}$.

For 1) note that (by going to a subsequence) we may suppose $u_n(c) \to u(c)$for some $c$  and $u_n \to u$ a.e.. Now $u_n(x)=u_n(c)+\int_c^{x}u_n'(t)dt=u_n(c)+\int_c^{x}[u_n'(c)+\int_c^{t}u_n''(s)ds]dt$.  I hope this is enough of  a hint!.

Comment: $u_n$ is not a valid counterexample: $u_n'' \to 0$ in $L^2$, which is continuous.

Comment: @daw $u_n'' =\frac {n-1} {n+1} x^{n-2} \to 0$ for $x <1$ and the limit is $1$ for $x=1$.

Comment: but $\{1\}$ has zero measure ...